# Docker swarm restart all containers on host periodically

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

I have next dmesg log

```
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:25 2020] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC=00:25:90:66:ab:2c:cc:4e:24:f9:de:60:08:00 SRC=185.176.27.162 DST=91.237.249.65 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=34473 PROTO=TCP SPT=42928 DPT=4443 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] veth13: renamed from vethdc65e40
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 3(veth13) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 3(veth13) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] device veth13 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] veth14: renamed from vethc274e51
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 4(veth14) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 4(veth14) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] device veth14 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 4(veth14) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 4(veth14) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] veth15: renamed from vethade6b91
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 5(veth15) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 5(veth15) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] device veth15 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 5(veth15) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] br0: port 5(veth15) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth39f34fb) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth39f34fb) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] device veth39f34fb entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth39f34fb: link is not ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth39f34fb) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth39f34fb) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth2dd14ef) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth2dd14ef) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] device veth2dd14ef entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth2dd14ef: link is not ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth2dd14ef) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth2dd14ef) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 10(veth253201d) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 10(veth253201d) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] device veth253201d entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth253201d: link is not ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 10(veth253201d) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:44 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 10(veth253201d) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] br0: port 4(veth14) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] br0: port 5(veth15) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth39f34fb) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth2dd14ef) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 10(veth253201d) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] eth0: renamed from veth9c853c4
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] br0: port 3(veth13) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] br0: port 3(veth13) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:45 2020] eth1: renamed from veth38928ee
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth39f34fb: link becomes ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth39f34fb) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth39f34fb) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] eth0: renamed from veth0a34354
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] br0: port 4(veth14) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] br0: port 4(veth14) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] eth1: renamed from veth3673041
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth2dd14ef: link becomes ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth2dd14ef) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:46 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth2dd14ef) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] br0: port 7(veth11) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] veth1545e82: renamed from eth0
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] br0: port 8(veth12) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] vethb08fde7: renamed from eth0
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(vethccff74f) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] veth590e84b: renamed from eth1
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] vethc6b5132: renamed from eth1
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth36b424b) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(vethccff74f) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] device vethccff74f left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(vethccff74f) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] eth0: renamed from vetha1f2897
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth36b424b) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] device veth36b424b left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth36b424b) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] br0: port 5(veth15) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] br0: port 5(veth15) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] br0: port 7(veth11) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] device veth11 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:47 2020] br0: port 7(veth11) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 8(veth12) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth12 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 8(veth12) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] eth1: renamed from veth56c6992
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth253201d: link becomes ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 10(veth253201d) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 10(veth253201d) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 5(veth462) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] vethd306c3b: renamed from eth0
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth7911ac5) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] veth41eb27e: renamed from eth1
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] veth467: renamed from veth780af70
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 4(veth467) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 4(veth467) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth467 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] veth22: renamed from veth23b3177
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth7911ac5) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth7911ac5 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth7911ac5) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 5(veth22) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 5(veth22) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth22 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] veth466: renamed from vethc0be03e
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 6(veth466) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 6(veth466) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth466 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] veth21: renamed from vethd3d6c20
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 6(veth21) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 6(veth21) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth21 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth2ec5aab) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth2ec5aab) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth2ec5aab entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth2ec5aab: link is not ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth2ec5aab) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth2ec5aab) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 5(veth462) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth462 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 5(veth462) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth2ec5aab) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] br0: port 6(veth10) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] vethcc03a84: renamed from eth0
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth69d8ae6) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth69d8ae6) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth69d8ae6 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth69d8ae6: link is not ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth69d8ae6) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth69d8ae6) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth5297c44) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth5297c44) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] device veth5297c44 entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth5297c44: link is not ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth5297c44) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth5297c44) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth69d8ae6) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth5297c44) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth122e42b) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:48 2020] vethe230f27: renamed from eth1
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 12(vetha0b790f) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 12(vetha0b790f) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] device vetha0b790f entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vetha0b790f: link is not ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 12(vetha0b790f) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 12(vetha0b790f) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth122e42b) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] device veth122e42b left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth122e42b) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] br0: port 6(veth10) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] device veth10 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] br0: port 6(veth10) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 12(vetha0b790f) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] eth0: renamed from vethea5f680
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] br0: port 5(veth22) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] br0: port 5(veth22) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] eth1: renamed from veth5f8bdfe
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth2ec5aab: link becomes ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth2ec5aab) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:49 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth2ec5aab) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:50 2020] eth0: renamed from vethb6652df
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:50 2020] br0: port 4(veth467) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:50 2020] br0: port 4(veth467) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:50 2020] eth1: renamed from vethcaadc3f
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:50 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth5297c44: link becomes ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:50 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth5297c44) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:50 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 11(veth5297c44) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:51 2020] eth0: renamed from vethb86f26f
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:51 2020] br0: port 6(veth21) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:51 2020] br0: port 6(veth21) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:51 2020] eth1: renamed from vethf0973ce
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:51 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetha0b790f: link becomes ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:51 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 12(vetha0b790f) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:51 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 12(vetha0b790f) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] br0: port 4(veth19) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] veth16921ae: renamed from eth0
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 7(vethd0e89d9) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] veth523fe30: renamed from eth1
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 7(vethd0e89d9) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] device vethd0e89d9 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 7(vethd0e89d9) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] br0: port 4(veth19) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] device veth19 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] br0: port 4(veth19) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] vethd713dc0: renamed from eth0
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] eth0: renamed from veth45b2428
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] br0: port 3(veth465) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] br0: port 6(veth466) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] br0: port 6(veth466) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] eth1: renamed from veth7af776c
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] veth6a2ad2f: renamed from eth1
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 1(vetha11775d) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth69d8ae6: link becomes ready
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth69d8ae6) entered blocking state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 8(veth69d8ae6) entered forwarding state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 1(vetha11775d) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] device vetha11775d left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 1(vetha11775d) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] br0: port 3(veth465) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] device veth465 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:52 2020] br0: port 3(veth465) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] br0: port 3(veth20) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] veth277410c: renamed from eth0
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 2(vethae76420) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] vethaafcc92: renamed from eth1
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 2(vethae76420) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] device vethae76420 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] docker_gwbridge: port 2(vethae76420) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] br0: port 3(veth20) entered disabled state
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] device veth20 left promiscuous mode
[Fri Jan 17 07:22:57 2020] br0: port 3(veth20) entered disabled state
```

with all docker containers restart at that time

```
ra@barn-01:~$ date
Fri Jan 17 07:27:45 EST 2020

ra@barn-01:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                NAMES
f0bcccb2a972        google/cadvisor:v0.33.0                            "/usr/bin/cadvisor -…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes (healthy)   8080/tcp             monitoring_cadvisor.952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3.pyg7escdnjv4sljelcuyklu4u
9b080faa0dad        stefanprodan/caddy:latest                          "/sbin/tini -- caddy…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                                  monitoring_dockerd-exporter.952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3.uxl34e3mgkia4uu348x246jrv
1a33343e0515        stefanprodan/swarmprom-node-exporter:v0.16.0       "/etc/node-exporter/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes             9100/tcp             monitoring_node-exporter.952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3.uisxqmds8lwhfkx6s6xy96o34
5294e5d15177        registry.speech.one/bakery-elastic:latest          "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes (healthy)   9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   prod_elastic-1.1.wtc9rdwvy2tspe6bdcz85fe29
fdff305d583d        registry.speech.one/bakery-postgres-slave:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes             5432/tcp             prod_postgres-slave-01.1.h1wbjo4nt1kjqm5x1qda99tb2
8ab7fca1d368        registry.speech.one/bakery-elastic:latest          "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes (healthy)   9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   preprod_elastic-1.1.8myb31cnrge2oe4ylmhgvno1n
```

and next journalctl log

```
sudo journalctl -u docker | tail -n 300
Jan 17 07:15:01 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:15:01.107574574-05:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats barn-01(96a9a06d3105) - netID:ih3ydbug5d7g4k7wvvqmt5a09 leaving:false netPeers:7 entries:90 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:1"
Jan 17 07:15:01 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:15:01.107614209-05:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats barn-01(96a9a06d3105) - netID:n58omezmixa5vi6z33v4js5l2 leaving:false netPeers:4 entries:36 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jan 17 07:15:01 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:15:01.107646380-05:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats barn-01(96a9a06d3105) - netID:myn3onq0xgdgenfc5i7zhm7ai leaving:false netPeers:11 entries:32 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jan 17 07:20:01 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:20:01.307417453-05:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats barn-01(96a9a06d3105) - netID:n58omezmixa5vi6z33v4js5l2 leaving:false netPeers:4 entries:36 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jan 17 07:20:01 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:20:01.307521188-05:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats barn-01(96a9a06d3105) - netID:myn3onq0xgdgenfc5i7zhm7ai leaving:false netPeers:11 entries:32 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jan 17 07:20:01 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:20:01.307555326-05:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats barn-01(96a9a06d3105) - netID:k37odopbgoyz9cpv3uilp1h1c leaving:false netPeers:11 entries:91 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jan 17 07:20:01 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:20:01.307595128-05:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats barn-01(96a9a06d3105) - netID:ih3ydbug5d7g4k7wvvqmt5a09 leaving:false netPeers:7 entries:90 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jan 17 07:22:05 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:05.107656164-05:00" level=info msg="memberlist: Suspect db085bc444b4 has failed, no acks received"
Jan 17 07:22:07 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:07.555466436-05:00" level=warning msg="memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: 716cf5e6e16c)"
Jan 17 07:22:09 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:09.467911262-05:00" level=error msg="heartbeat to manager {cc8p2g9w23yftc4py6rozjkie 95.213.131.210:2377} failed" error="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" method="(*session).heartbeat" module=node/agent node.id=952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3 session.id=da35coq44b4iwzy6godo878eq sessionID=da35coq44b4iwzy6godo878eq
Jan 17 07:22:09 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:09.468021277-05:00" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=100ms error="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" module=node/agent node.id=952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3
Jan 17 07:22:09 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:09.468132554-05:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"\"" module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:09 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:09.468156403-05:00" level=info msg="scheme \"\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:09 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:09.468473713-05:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{141.105.66.236:2377 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:09 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:09.468503514-05:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:09 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:09.468540108-05:00" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {yz8061f18re1xpzlalej82t61 141.105.66.236:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3
Jan 17 07:22:09 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:09.468586653-05:00" level=info msg="waiting 79.132044ms before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3
Jan 17 07:22:10 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:10.107678076-05:00" level=info msg="memberlist: Suspect 716cf5e6e16c has failed, no acks received"
Jan 17 07:22:14 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:14.355515631-05:00" level=warning msg="memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: 619baf78f350)"
Jan 17 07:22:14 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:14.548130146-05:00" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=300ms error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3
Jan 17 07:22:14 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:14.548253430-05:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"\"" module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:14 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:14.548277506-05:00" level=info msg="scheme \"\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:14 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:14.548589274-05:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{92.53.64.188:2377 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:14 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:14.548620610-05:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:14 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:14.548661631-05:00" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {l6dndjoram0ptqsf370oe4njw 92.53.64.188:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3
Jan 17 07:22:14 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:14.548717648-05:00" level=info msg="waiting 208.067334ms before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=952iedkyjkv6up55rq7i64pc3
Jan 17 07:22:15 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:15.107515174-05:00" level=info msg="memberlist: Suspect db085bc444b4 has failed, no acks received"
Jan 17 07:22:15 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:15.947277092-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap."
Jan 17 07:22:15 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:15.949633840-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap."
Jan 17 07:22:15 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:15.950608296-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap."
Jan 17 07:22:15 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:15.951657739-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap."
Jan 17 07:22:15 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:15.952975690-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap."
Jan 17 07:22:16 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:16.676033275-05:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {141.105.66.236:2377 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: authentication handshake failed: context canceled\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
Jan 17 07:22:19 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:19.057434028-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 17 07:22:19 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:19.058114454-05:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding f9b34a20e073bc91ed98cdb9faaa4d8442a757e75f97d1aa28a1e83273c99469 possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Jan 17 07:22:19 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:19.072272034-05:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 3593899b8d90ee70846fedbbbc9996d4d5f6ab9f37978d7fdc23e724b60866cb possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Jan 17 07:22:19 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:19.072350716-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 17 07:22:19 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:19.675287095-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 17 07:22:19 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:19.725847111-05:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding d85c7160ff7ad71d477f17796b8e786cb716d2c5f46ceff498794a5afeb0fdca possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Jan 17 07:22:19 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:19.796223977-05:00" level=warning msg="7ae0ab97d1a78f4a09e52fe911e447dd5ced1f604623d77a2ae8b97790272630 cleanup: failed to unmount IPC: umount /var/lib/docker/containers/7ae0ab97d1a78f4a09e52fe911e447dd5ced1f604623d77a2ae8b97790272630/mounts/shm, flags: 0x2: no such file or directory"
Jan 17 07:22:19 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:19.922030007-05:00" level=warning msg="79e50c97f9ed5a7fda2eb75f7e891159c6405792af2e917f176a3d2442e63c73 cleanup: failed to unmount IPC: umount /var/lib/docker/containers/79e50c97f9ed5a7fda2eb75f7e891159c6405792af2e917f176a3d2442e63c73/mounts/shm, flags: 0x2: no such file or directory"
Jan 17 07:22:20 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:20.393450301-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 17 07:22:20 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:20.451602909-05:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 938b93a3ac83e44f0eee9b0486f8c1088559a5fb34dd94afa07bdf00d9c4504e possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Jan 17 07:22:20 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:20.632699969-05:00" level=warning msg="5b97bff7a1978a559bbcab3a3e457edb6f60ea54ae2ae209bd23540d5dd29140 cleanup: failed to unmount IPC: umount /var/lib/docker/containers/5b97bff7a1978a559bbcab3a3e457edb6f60ea54ae2ae209bd23540d5dd29140/mounts/shm, flags: 0x2: no such file or directory"
Jan 17 07:22:20 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:20.907207465-05:00" level=warning msg="e329ee187f0f479f50a8b1ada9a24222d41e34c86fe6819cdf471821a66ebda0 cleanup: failed to unmount IPC: umount /var/lib/docker/containers/e329ee187f0f479f50a8b1ada9a24222d41e34c86fe6819cdf471821a66ebda0/mounts/shm, flags: 0x2: no such file or directory"
Jan 17 07:22:21 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:21.735004502-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 17 07:22:21 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:21.735475195-05:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 4ee9822b62ef9b74a89fdcced36f818f8f1906502fc6a314e14445868f73dabf possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Jan 17 07:22:24 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:24.145639956-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 17 07:22:24 barn-01 dockerd[1649]: time="2020-01-17T07:22:24.146278837-05:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 7fed4a57d7ed72527ce39257f2d643724faa788243a682de879df08460cb377f possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
```

seems to be connected with
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38203

I have periodically this issue. Any ideas why? And how to avoid it ?

Update:
find discussion 
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3374

and fix
https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/pull/2380
which should be in docker 19.03.6

Update: still have the problem in 19.03.6

Comment: Is there any memory leak in your container app. After certain memory allocation limit, container would crash and restart. Have to checked this?

Comment: This is not a question about coding. SO is not a free support site to submit your logs and ask people to debug.